# Why doesn't my computer list Android devices in Device Manager, or detect my Sony Xperia Play (R800)?

Tags: adb, windows, sony-xperia

I have an ancient Sony Xperia Play that I am trying to root. However, I can't even get it to show up on my computer.

It's possible that I accidentally deleted my drivers by running an unroot script. However, since then I've tried the following:

- enabling mass storage mode, debug mode and unknown sources on my phone;
- installing Android SDK, the usb drivers, and multiple versions of abd;
- removing superfluous drivers (but I can still run "Minimal ABD & Flashboot"...?) & installing Koush's adb driver.

Absolutely no option for "Android Device Bridge" (or its various aliases), nor the phone itself, shows up in the device manager when I connect the phone via USB. When I run abd devices, no devices show up. I don't really know what I'm doing, any advice as to what could be the problem?

[image: running adb devices]

[image: what my device mgr looks like]